# How change routing type of ActiveMQ Artemis queue via core API

Tags: queue, message-queue, multicast, activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0. I want to change routing type exist queue via core API from Java client. I tried this:

```java
...

    QueueSession session = createSession(connection)
    Message message = session.createMessage();
    final QueueConfiguration queueConfiguration = new org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.QueueConfiguration('testQueue');
            queueConfiguration.setRoutingType(org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.RoutingType.MULTICAST);
    queueConfiguration.setAddress('testQueue');
    queueConfiguration.setAutoCreateAddress(true);
            
    JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(message, 'testQueue', 'updateQueue', queueConfiguration.toJSON());
    Message reply = requestor.request(message);
```

I receive this error:

```
AMQ229069: no operation updateQueue/1
```

Also `ClientSession` has methods `createQueue` and `deleteQueue` but not `updateQueue`. How can I change a queue from the client API?

Comment: 2.17, but i decided my problem. thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. First, create an address with 2 routing-types, e.g.:

```java
ClientSession session ...
...
session.createAddress(SimpleString.toSimpleString('testAddress'), EnumSet.allOf(RoutingType.class), false);
```

Next, create queue with this address:

```java
final QueueConfiguration queueConfiguration = new QueueConfiguration('testQueue');
queueConfiguration.setRoutingType(RoutingType.ANYCAST);
queueConfiguration.setAddress('testAddress');
queueConfiguration.setAutoCreateAddress(false);
session.createQueue(queueConfiguration);
```

and exactly at this queue can change routing type

```java
Queue managementQueue = session.createQueue(MANAGEMENT_QUEUE);
requestor = new QueueRequestor(session, managementQueue);
connection.start();
Message message = session.createMessage();
JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(message, 'broker', 'updateQueue', 'testQueue', 'MULTICAST', 2, false);

Message reply = requestor.request(message);
```